# Tail recursion [C]

Tags: c, recursion, tail-recursion, tail-call-optimization, tail-call

The question in my book is "Which of the recursive calls (not functions!) are tail recursive?"

```
unsigned f(unsigned x) 
{ 
    if(x==0) return 1; 
    else if(x==1) return f(x-1); 
    else return 3*x + f(x-1); 
}
```

In this example, I'm guessing that the first one is tail recursive, but the second one is not. However, what happens in the following case, where we also have `printf()` before and after the recursive call(s)?

```
void f(unsigned x) 
{
    if(x==0) return;
    else if(x==1) { f(x-1); printf("1"); }
    else if(x==2) { printf("2"); f(x-1); }
    else f(x-3);
}
```

Considering what I so far know about tail recursion, my guess was that the first one isn't, but the second and the third one are? Am I wrong, and if so, could you please explain how this works?

Comment: You're correct on all counts.

Comment: A recursive call is tail-recursive if the function immediately returns after making the call.

Comment: Note that in C++ tail recursion is not special according to the Standard. One _requirement_ imposed on implementations of a language to explicitly support tail calls that I know is http://www.schemers.org/Documents/Standards/R5RS/HTML/

Comment: Related: [What is tail recursion?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37010)

Comment: @bipll Question is tag C and Standard C don't guaranty tail recursion call too by the way.

Comment: Yes, C. But they're not different in this aspect anyway.

Answer (score 2):

In your first example, you are right that only the first call is potentially tail-recursive.

In the second example, the first call to `printf()` is potentially a tail-call, and the second and third call to `f()` are potentially tail-recursive.

It depends on the details of your implementation, and while the used ABI might give a hint (which is why the call to `f()` is more likely to be tail-recursive than the call to `printf()` a tail-call), that evidence is decidedly weak.
The standard is silent on those points.

Comment: You have to admire the certainty surrounding the issue. Certainly gives the compiler writers a bit of freedom to handle the cases as they like.